# Including Relay child fragments with no fields for current component

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay

I have the following components:

**Position**

```
const Position = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <LinkSummary linkSummary={this.props.position.linkSummary} />
    );
  }
});

const PositionContainer = Relay.createContainer(Position, {
  fragments: {
    position: Relay.QL`
      fragment on Position {
        text
        linkSummary {
          ${LinkSummary.getFragment('linkSummary')}
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

**LinkSummary**

```
const LinkSummary = React.createClass({ ... });

const LinkSummaryContainer = Relay.createContainer(LinkSummary, {
  fragments: {
    linkSummary: Relay.QL`
      fragment on LinkSummary {
        url
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

The above throws an error in `Position`, where it claims that I can't:

> Uncaught Error: GraphQL validation error ``Cannot query field "linkSummary" on type "Position".``

If I change the fragment on `Position` to include any field from `LinkSummary`, it works. I.E.

```
fragment on Position {
  text
  linkSummary {
    description
    ${LinkSummary.getFragment('linkSummary')}
  }
}
```

Is it not possible to just want to include the child fragment, but not use any part of that field for the current container? How else should I specify the child fragment? Worst case scenario, I could change the `LinkSummary` container to accept the entire Position and then just include its fragment in `PositionContainer` at the same level as every other field, but that seems wrong since `LinkSummary` is its own type in my schema.

Comment: In your schema, does `Position` have a field `LinkSummary`? Because that's what Relay is looking for.

Comment: Yes, it does. And as I mentioned, the query works with an additional field so `LinkSummary` is most certainly being found on `Position`

Comment: yea, you are right. That's tricky.

Comment: I'm assuming I have something wrong with my schema, because I'm pretty sure the just-child fragment query is valid, right?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your schema?

Comment: @AndrewIngram do you want the JS code or the compiles .graphql version?